# sqrt time complexity comparison

Tags: c++, sqrt

Is this loop --

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < sqrt(number) ; i++)
{
    //some operations
}
```

faster than this --

```
int length = sqrt(number);
for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
{
    //some operations
}
```

I was getting TLE in a code in an online judge but when i replaced sqrt in loop with length i got it accepted.

Can u please point out the time complexity of the loop with sqrt considering `number to be <=1000000000`

Comment: suppose n = sqrt(number), if you place sqrt(number) in for loop, sqrt(number) would be calculated n times. So, no matter how complex the function sqrt is, it is always not good enough. By the way, the complexity of sqrt is O(logn)

Comment: @finesse, the *most usual* complexity of `sqrt` may be O(log N) but it's by no means mandated. I could write an O(N) one which simply checks all possibilities in sequence or I could, given the memory, use a table lookup which gives O(1) :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo，you are right, I'm reading a paper which talk about "Fast Inverse Square Root", a O(1) method to implement sqrt. And, table lookup algorithm are not O(1) in space, so I don't think a c lib function is implemented by this way. After all, table lookup need to be init first time.

Comment: @fitnesse-can you post a link to the paper

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The time complexity itself isn't different between the two loops (unless the complexity of `sqrt` itself is dependent on the number) but what *is* different is how many times you're computing the square root.

Without optimisation like the compiler automatically moving loop invariant stuff outside of the loop (assuming that's even allowed in this case since the compiler would have to check a lot of things to ensure they can't affect the result or side effects of the `sqrt` call), the following code will calculate the square root about a thousand times (once per iteration):

```
number = 1000000;
for(int i = 0 ; i < sqrt(number) ; i++) { ... }
```

However, *this* code will only calculate it once:

```
number = 1000000;
root = sqrt(number);
for(int i = 0 ; i < root ; i++) { ... }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that it's so easy for the compiler to move the invariant out of the loop due to its side effects (namely, `errno` potentially being set to `EDOM`) and to the fact that the inside of the loop may change the FP flags. I would be surprised to see it moved out if the loop body contains even just a function call.

Comment: Good point, @Matteo. While a fixed `number` with all other things constant means `sqrt` would have to return the same value each time, fiddling with the floating point flags may well affect the result. Added caveat to cover that.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, may be we don't need to consider the compiler optimize. Do you think is there any possibility that math functions like sqrt should use some cache internal?

Comment: @finesse: caching for stuff like that would probably be way slower than recalculating - after all, if you tell the compiler to ignore the useless niceties required by the standard (=`errno`) it boils down to a single x87 instruction, while keeping a cache would involve some high level lookup code (and some potential cache misses). But in general, I never assume that the compiler will be too smart about FP, both because it has some serious hidden state (FP flags, dead `errno` stores), and because FP peculiarities (non-associativity, non-commutativity, ...) makes many optimizations unsafe.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the whole expression `i < sqrt(number)` must be evaluated repeatedly in the original code, while `sqrt` is evaluated only once in the modified code.

Well, the recent compilers are usually able to optimize the loop so the `sqrt` is evaluated only once before the loop, but do you want to rely on them?

Answer (score 2):

The first version forces the compiler to generate code that executes `sqrt(number)` every time the condition is tested (as many times as the for is looped).

The second version only calculates the length once (single call to `sqrt`).